# How to create a function to use a bunch of classes

Tags: c#, class

[image: These are the models]

So I have some classes as models and i want to create a function that can use these models
As you can see the below function converts to a text file and I have different models that come under model namespace (as personModel,teamModel,etc.)) to convert to text file so i was thinking of creating a class that takes any model and convert it to text file
I am still learing things so i dont know if its possible or not.I think so it is Please HELP!

THANK YOU

```
 public static List<PrizeModel> ConvertToPrizeModel(this List<string> lines)
 {
     List<PrizeModel> output = new List<PrizeModel>();
     foreach (string line in lines)
     {
         string[] cols = line.Split(',');
         PrizeModel p = new PrizeModel();
         p.Id = int.Parse(cols[0]);
         p.PlaceNumber = int.Parse(cols[1]);
         p.PlaceName = cols[2];
         p.PrizeAmount = decimal.Parse(cols[3]);
         p.PrizePercentage = double.Parse(cols[4]);
         output.Add(p);
     }  
     return output;
 }
```

I can create different function for each models but i want to learn if i can make one function

Comment: You are recreating the wheel.  There are gobs of well written libraries to parse CSV files into collections of classes.  Start by looking at CSVHelper

Comment: You need to read [Serialization in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/)

Comment: A note about the link shingo posted: for the love of god, stay far away from binaryFormatter. Xml and json are both fine, but binaryFormatter is terrible, and have been removed in later .Net versions..

Comment: Also consider using a database instead of text files. You can start small and easy with a single- file local db like SQLite or LiteDB or something similar. The latter even comes with its own micro-orm.

Comment: @Fildor Thanks for the suggestion i am using MSSQL also and its going well . Since i am learning I was just curious .

Answer (score 1):

You should use a serialization library. These take objects and convert them to either text or binary data that can be written to a file, and also does the reverse.

There are many formats and libraries to chose from, but a very common choice is [system.text.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to). It should look something like:

```
var myPriceModels = new List<PriceModel>(){...}
string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(myPriceModels );
var deserializedPriceModels = 
                JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<PriceModel>>(jsonString);
```

Much simpler than parsing individual values by hand.

There are typically some requirements for using such libraries.

1. You often need public setters and getters for all properties.
2. You often need a public parameterless constructor.
3. You can often use attributes to specify how serialization should be performed. Some libraries require attributes.
4. You can often use attributes to do [polymorphic serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism?pivots=dotnet-7-0)

You might want to use separate types specifically for serialization. Often called 'Data Transfer Objects', or DTOs. This allow for better separation between code for logic and storage, as well as greater flexibility in case the model changes. At the cost of more code and classes.

Using standard formats and libraries to save/load data will likely make your code faster, more reliable, and easier to read and use. Note for example that your posted code will very likely fail when run somewhere else in the world, since you are not specifying the culture to use when parsing values.

Answer (score -1):

Use [Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics) and reflection.

You can use something like this:

```
public static List<T> ConvertToModelList<T>(this List<string> lines) where T : new()
{
    List<T> output = new List<T>();
    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        string[] cols = line.Split(',');

        T model = new T();
        for (int i = 0; i < cols.Length; i++)
        {
            PropertyInfo property = properties[i];
            object value = Convert.ChangeType(cols[i], property.PropertyType);
            property.SetValue(model, value);
        }

        output.Add(model);
    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Note that reflection is slow and you lose any type-safety. Also, just assuming that the order of the columns in the input exactly corresponds to the order of properties returned by `Type.GetProperties` is maybe fragile.